# Access web browser client's device files from the web application?

Tags: node.js, security, web

Because of security reason it is not allowed to access web browser client's device file from the web application. Is it possible to get an access after getting permission from client user? How one can achieve this? 
Note: Web application is written in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a client side application using NodeWebkit. It has been renamed nw.js it allows you to create a desktop application which can make the standard HTTP, etc... requests to your server. You can also wrap your application in order to make it a downloadable mobile app.